# Base conversion in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, radix, digits

I need help to understand this question. Please don't post the answer, only the ways to solve it.

> Assign `10` to the variable `base`. Assign the set `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`
>   to the variable `digits`. Now write an expression using a comprehension
>   and `base` and `digits` whose value is the set of all at-most- three-digit
>   numbers. Your expression should work for any base. For example, if you
>   instead assign `2` to base and assign `{0,1}` to digits, the value of your
>   expression should be `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` because this is the set of
>   numbers that, base two, have at most three digits.

I try this expression but I could not solve the base 2 question.

```
base = 10
digits = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
{(x*(base**2))+(y*(base**1))+(z*(base**0)) for x in digits for y in digits for z in digits if (x*(base**2))+(y*(base**1))+(z*(base**0))>((y*(base**1))+(z*(base**0)))}
```

Comment: I would recomend finding the largest value in the set of digits.  I would then just do `range(int('%s%s%s'%(max_digit,max_digit_max_digit),base)+1)` but that probably isnt what your teacher wants

Comment: I need to come up with a comprehension that return a {100-999} set for decimals and the same expression should work with any base ex: 2,8 16...

Comment: I recognise this question as being from the Coursera matrix/linear algebra course. You should really look on the course discussion board there, rather than asking for help here.

Comment: your code seems to work fine ... "At most 3 characters" not "exactly 3 characters"  ... just get rid of the `if` in the comprehension

Comment: Actually you need to come up with a generator that will give you all the three digit numbers in the range 001 to MMM where M is max digit  this will automatically include the one and two digit numbers by allowing leading 0s.  The other hints look at the output of python -c "print help(int)"...

Answer (score 2):

> ...whose value is the set of all **at-most-** three-digit numbers.

Emphasis added.  You need to include the values `000` - `099` (for `base = 10`).

It looks like you've almost got it. You don't need a filter in your comprehension.  Think about how many results you'll get from `for x in digits for y in digits for z in digits` for different values in `digits`. It should be exactly the right number of values.

Answer (score 1):

You already had the answer, simply remove the `if` statement. Try this:

```
{x*base**2+y*base**1+z*base**0 for x in digits for y in digits for z in digits}
```

If you use base 10 and digits (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) you should get a list from from 0 to 999. And if you use base 2 and digits (0,1) you should get a list from 0 to 7.

Answer (score 1):

As I guess your homework is done, almost two years later:

The number of 3 digits number within your base is a sequence of the form

```
base^digits
```

For example, to have the number of 3-digits numbers in base ten, one would type in python:

```
10**3
```

You then can use the range function to have them all:

```
{x for x in range(10**3)}
```

This works with any base.